# Как расположить блоки рядом?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, необходимо расположить два блока рядом, не понимаю как это делается вообще, пишут, что через flexbox но я не догоняю как это сделать...

Comment: position: absolute; и дальше подстраиваете значение margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flexbox`

```css
#a {
  background: blue;
}

#b {
  background: red;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

`inline-block`

```css
#a {
  background: blue;
}

#b {
  background: red;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div><!-- обязательно комментарий, чтобы не было гэпа
--><div id="b"></div>
```

`float: left`

```css
#a {
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#b {
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Comment: А как между ними расстояние делать?

Comment: @АлексейРешетило, `margin-right` для левого, либо `margin-left` для правого.